# How to add secondary Y-axis in RadCartesianChart windows store apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

we are developing an windows 8 store apps and telerik charts to display charts. In one of the charts we need to show the chart having 2 y-axis and bar series need to bind to left side of the y-axis and line series need to bind data to right side of the y-axis(secondary y-axis). So i posted in one of the forum and got reply form them and i like to share the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I suggest. You have to create a class that inherits the Collection class in your project.

```
public class CustomAxes : Collection<Axis> { }
```

This will make it possible to define custom collection of axes that will be used by the corresponding series. Next you have to create `CustomAxes` object in the resources of your application and fill it with the axes you want to have in your chart:

```
<local:CustomAxes x:Key="customAxes">
   <telerik:LinearAxis HorizontalLocation="Left"/>
   <telerik:LinearAxis HorizontalLocation="Right"/>
</local:CustomAxes>
```

Now you have to bind the vertical axes of your series to the custom axes:

```
<telerik:BarSeries VerticalAxis="{Binding Source={StaticResource customAxes}, Path=[0]}">
```

Here is the sample code attached [in this forum](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/metro/chart-xaml/how-to-add-two-line-series-to-a-single-secondary-y-axis-in-radcartesianchart.aspx).